# Preventing root from viewing personal user accounts in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, sudo

Let's say a ubuntu computer is shared by 2 developers, John and Bob. They both have the root/sudo password, but want to keep their personal data from each other. Would encrypting (eCryptFS?) their home directories sufficient enough (assuming no keyloggers or complicated hacks, this is just for a simple layer of security)? Root/sudo password is needed for apt install/developer stuffs.

A solution to this is to have a user called work that can use programs like Docker (so that they don't need to use sudo all the time, and only one instance of Docker is installed, along with other programs like IntelliJ, Visual Studio Code, Android Studio). So whenever John or Bob needs to be in 'developer mode' they can use `su - work`. `work` is not encrypted.

Is this the best way to do about this?

Comment: EFS would indeed protect you from other users.

Comment: nope, only one user at a time.. personal stuffs is mainly the browser (firefox, with lastpass and email logged in), and text files.. maybe it's overkill to have another user with encrypted home? just make an encrypted folder that has those files? then i can decrypt/run firefox/files (personal) whenever needed, and encrypt it again

Comment: Note that encryption would prevent John looking at Bob's directory when Bob is not logged it, but when Bob is logged in and his directory is mounted, John could remotely log in (via `ssh`) and see Bob's files. IMHO the best way to go about this is to declare this a developer machine, declare the home directories job-related only, and have no data in there that the other developer shouldn't see. Another option is to give each developer their own machine, virtual or physical.